# Maintaining a transaction flow using Jersey REST

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I am pretty new to the REST world and we are trying our hands at migrating our application to a REST based architecture. We are working on a proof of concept and we need to come up with a working proof that what we are set to achieve can be done using REST.

In our architecture, the front end screens would use Angular and would call REST services to open up a customer session and perform/maintain transactions within that session and when the session is complete, the session details (i.e. all the customer transactions within the customer session) would be sent over for commit to the DB. We only want to write to the DB after customer completes all transactions within a session. In other words, a commit to the DB happens only when the session ends.

I am hoping to get some directions on how best to perform the below steps in our Java classes.

1) Browser initiates a request to open a new customer session. A session POST service is used to generate a new session ID. The session ID is sent back as response to the browser.

**Question -->** *What is the best way to maintain this session ID value in my Java classes?*

2) Customer transactions are performed within the session. For each transaction processed a transaction POST service is used to save the transaction information along with the session information.

**Question -->** *In my Java classes what is the best way to maintain this transaction information and how best do I associate this transaction information with the session information that was created by the previous session POST information? The client would maintain the session ID but on the service side I need to be able to map the transaction with the session ID so that I can send back a combined session payload that includes session information and the transaction within that session.*

3) A customer can perform some more transactions and each transaction performed would be a transaction POST request which would have to get associated with the session id created before. Each additional transaction performed would have to be associated to the session id on the service side such that when I do a GET on the session id, I need to get the session details along with all transactions within that session.

4) Finally when the session is complete the information from the session and the session payload on the service side (along with all the transactions) will commit to the DB.

I am just looking for some general guidance on how best to do this using my Java classes and Jersey REST.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks
Ali.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this question isn't easy and requires a lot of writing, however I'll try to reply.

First of all remember that REST is stateless - it means that there's no session and client needs to be authorized with *every* request. This is a separate topic but a nice authorization method in REST is [JSON Web Token](http://jwt.io/).

Secondly REST is about nouns - not verbs. Thus you should avoid URLs like `/session/{sessionId}/close/` but try to model the domain using nouns and default HTTP operations: POST (create), PUT (update), GET (read), DELETE (remove).

I guess that session and transactions is just an abstraction I will show you how to model it on an example of shopping cart. In all examples I doubled the URLs - `with /users/{userId}/` prefix to show you can refer to resources in many different ways

1. Create a shopping cart (creating a session)

   ```
   POST /shopping-carts/
   POST /users/{userID}/shopping-carts/
   ```

   Request: may be empty or should contain necessary details about the cart

   Response: must contain a newly-created shoppingCartID

   ```
   {
      "shoppingCartID": "1qaz2wsx"
      ... 
   }
   ```
2. Add an item to a shopping cart (create a transaction)

   ```
   POST /shopping-carts/{shoppingCartID}/items/
   POST /users/{userID}/shopping-carts/{shoppingCartID}/items/
   ```

   Request: contains details about an item being added

   Response: returns a newly-added item along with its unique ID
3. Pay for the shopping cart (commit the transactions)

   ```
   POST /payments/
   POST /users/{userID}/payments/
   ```

   Request: must contain a `shoppingCartID`

   ```
   {
       "shoppingCartID": "1qaz2wsx"
       ...
   }
   ```

   Response: Contains details about newly-created payment

   ```
   {
       "paymentId": "3edc4rfv"
       ...
   }
   ```

I know that this is a general answer but it's difficult to give a precise answer for such a wide question.

**EDIT** (after a discussion in comments)

In my opinion the DB should be used to keep the transactions in a temporary table before they are approved. Even if you don't want to use a DB any other persistent store is highly recommended - imagine what could happen in case of a server restart when transactions are not approved, you will lose all the data.

The options I see:

- In memory. You can write a simple in-memory structure with a synchronized access. In the most simple case just plain old `HashMap` will be enough. Mind the fact that keeping data this way is risky, the can be erased very easily.
- Use file system. If you don't want to use DB you can use file system to keep the transactions data while they're uncommitted. After adding a new transaction it's written to a file. On commit file is read and all transactions are saved to DB. A synchronized file access is also very important here. When it comes to data format you can use JSON, XML, even plain java serialization.
- The last idea that comes to my head is to use an in memory DB, such as Redis. The data will be erased on a system reboot so they're less likely to be deleted, however this is not safe in my opinion as well. Such DB is much easier to use/maintain than traditional DB.

It all depends what are you trying to implement. I can't imagine a scenario where uncommitted transactions can be simply removed and nothing happens - it seems that there's a must for persistent storage. However the ideas above might be useful as well.

Comment: Thanks @Opal for taking the time. I do have the understanding for REST calls nailed down. What I was looking for was guidance on best practices to build and hold the payload for a specific customer. Using your example above, when customer creates a shopping cart the POST service needs to create an object that holds the session id. Subsequent adds to the shopping cart should keep building on to that object created before in memory. At any given point of time, if from another browser I do a GET this same session id, I want to be able to get all the transactions that customer added to the cart.

Comment: If I can help further the question needa to be clarified then.

Comment: I am looking for pointers on best ways to hold a session object for a particular shopping cart that a customer started (after the POST shopping-carts). I get the piece where you would do an individual POST for each transaction added to the cart. Looking for ways to associate those transactions back to the session id created by the previous post in such a way that when I do a GET on the shopping-carts (in other words view shopping cart) it has to give me the shopping cart content listed with all the transactions that were individually created using individual REST POST.

Comment: Let me know if I am still not making myself clear and I will try to explain in a different way.

Comment: So you ask not about REST itself but how to handle it on the backend side, yes?

Comment: Yes. In essence that's what I am looking for. The POC we are doing is to prove that REST works but I need to be able to construct and maintain the payload on the service level without having to use a DB. When any rest call is made from the browser the constructed model needs to be shown on that browser.